# aggregate list with linq with sum

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

i am trying to consolidate an ienumerable list that i am serializing

i have data that looks like this:

```
Internet explorer    10
Internet explorer    15 
Mozille firefox      10
```

I was it to look like:

```
Internet explorer    25
Mozille firefox      10
```

my class looks like:

```
 public class BrowserVisits
 {
  public string BrowserName { get; set; }

  public int Visits { get; set; }
        }
```

my current query to serialize an ienumerable list (r) looks like:

```
var browserVisits = from r in reportData
      select new BrowserVisits
      {
       BrowserName = r.Dimensions.First(d => d.Key == Dimension.Browser).Value,
       Visits = int.Parse(r.Metrics.First(d => d.Key == Metric.Visits).Value)
      };
```

how do i go a group by with sum in linq?

do i need to go two queries, or can i do a single one.

apologies if this sounds vague, its been a long day, but am more than happy to add to this if it needs clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
public static IEnumerable<BrowserVisits> SumGroups(
    IEnumerable<BrowserVisits> visits)
{
    return visits.GroupBy(
        i => i.BrowserName,
        (name, browsers) => new BrowserVisits() {
            BrowserName = name,
            Visits = browsers.Sum(i => i.Visits)
        });
}
```

This works for me against your sample data.

Comment: am i able to do it in a single query? instead of two? so the same as my original but with additional colsolidation of the original group? i'm working on windows phone SDK so trying to make it as lean as possible

Comment: @Doug: Using the result of this method in another query counts as a "single query" since the execution of this query will be deferred until it is enumerated, just like any other LINQ query.

Comment: the second i started reading your comment, it hit me before i had finished reading - will give it a try now

Answer (score 3):

```
var lstBrowserVisits = new List<BrowserVisits> 
            { 

                new BrowserVisits{BrowserName = "Internet explorer", Visits = 10},
                new BrowserVisits{BrowserName = "Internet explorer", Visits = 15},
                new BrowserVisits{BrowserName = "Mozille firefox", Visits = 10} 
            }; 

var res = (from browserVisit in lstBrowserVisits
           group browserVisit by browserVisit.BrowserName into g
           select new { BrowserName = g.Key, Visits = g.Sum(s => s.Visits) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Name                     Value

Internet explorer      10 
Internet explorer      15 
Mozille firefox           10

```
var sum= list.GroupBy(a => a.Name).Select(a => new { Total= a.Sum(b => b.value),Name= a.Key }).OrderByDescending(a => a.Total).ToList();
```