# Aggregate List Based on Child Properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have an class structure representing an item's list of materials, with each material having a list of additional properties.  Similar to the following:

- `MaterialList`

  - `MaterialPiece`

    - `AdditionalPropertyList`

      - `AdditionalProperties`

Each class has a `ChildPieces` list property containing the list of items in the next level; for example, the `MaterialList` class has

```
public List<MaterialPiece> ChildPieces {get;set;}
```

So an example instance of this might be

- WheelSet

  - Wheel

    - Wheel Properties

      - Quantity: 1
      - Partnumber: R1000
  - Wheel

    - Wheel Properties

      - Quantity: 1
      - Partnumber: R1000

What I want to do is aggregate the MaterialList to group together the MaterialPiece objects based on some of their properties - the Partnumber in the above example.

This would result in

- WheelSet

  - Wheel

    - Wheel Properties

      - Quantity: 2
      - Partnumber: R1000

I want to do this in the outermost object, i.e. I want to implement

```
class MaterialList : BasePiece
{
    public void AggregateMaterialPieces()
    {
        var newList = ChildPieces.Where(...)
    }
}
```

**So my question:** Can I use LINQ to group and sum the MaterialPieces in the MaterialList based on some known values in the AdditionalPropertyList?

Comment: This sounds like a job for... **`SelectMany`-Man**! Something like `ChildPieces.SelectMany(piece => piece.AdditionalPropertyList)` will get you a single collection containing all the items contained by every additional property list. Not sure if that's a complete answer, but it should be a helpful step.

Comment: @Magus - will that allow me to not flatten the structure?  i.e. I still want a discrete list of `MaterialPiece` objects, but grouped by one of the `AdditionalProperties` entries, and summing on another.

Comment: @Geoff you can do flatten structure and then group as you want

Comment: Linq has `Select` if you don't want to flatten things, as well as `GroupBy` and such. You have options.

Comment: @Magus - Thanks, I was working with Select and Sum based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4487389/55487), but I was struggling to figure out how to make it work with a nested structure like the one I have (hence my question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't quite specific enough but anyway, here's some code that will give you the quantities for each partnumber.

```
 var groupings = list.SelectMany(x => x.AdditionalPropertyList).GroupBy(x => x.PartNumber).Select(g => new { PartNumber=g.Key, Quantity=g.Sum(x => x.Quantity) } );

 foreach (var g in groupings)
    Console.WriteLine("PartNumer: {0} Total: {1}", g.PartNumber, g.Quantity);
```

I'm not positive this is correct, if it doesn't work let me know and I'll try to make time to actually test it. The basic idea is to flatten the list to all the additional properties, then you group those by partnumber, then for each of the groupings you create a new anonymous object which uses the partnumber (the group key) and calls aggregate on the list of groupings to get the sum of all the quantities.

Comment: Thanks! First, I'm happy to be more specific if you can describe what I am missing?  I'm starting to understand that to do a `GroupBy` I need to effectively destroy (i.e. omit) the old child objects and create a new aggregated object, but the part that's throwing me is that there is two levels hanging below the child.  In my example, I'm guessing I omit the two Wheel objects and create a new Wheel with aggregated quantity, but how do I create those additional levels within LINQ?  Or am I better off finding another way?

Comment: @Geoff yeah, my code doesn't quite work but would be getting rid of those other levels so you just have a list of objects where each object has a PartNumber and the total quantity for that partnumber. I don't know how to do what you want, I think it might be simpler to break into multiple LINQ queries.

Comment: @Geoff I fixed my code because it now does what I want, not necessarily what you're looking for but probably about as close as you're going to get. At least with it all being a single LINQ query.